# Django chart.js multi axis line chart

Tags: django, charts, chart.js

Hi Guys I have inspired from this [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/vjt2r1mL/) to try to  create a similar multi axis line chart in my django project.
I have in my views :

```
class dashboard(TemplateView):
template_name = 'users/dashboard.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['qs'] = DummyData.objects.all()
    data = DummyData.objects.all()
    years=[]
    for i in range(data.count()) :
        if data[i].year not in years :
            years.append(data[i].year)

    context['years'] = years
    return context
```

in in my dashboard.html :

```
    {% extends 'users/base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %}


    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- semantic UI -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css">
    <!--Chart js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>



<script>
     $(document).ready(function (){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [{% for year in years %} '{{year}}', {% endfor %}],
    datasets: [{% for item in qs %}
    {
      label: '{{item.site}}',
      yAxisID: '{{item.site}}',
      data: [100, 96, 84, 76, 69] , {% endfor %}
  ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'A',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'left',
      }, {
        id: 'B',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          max: 1,
          min: 0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
     });
 </script>
   <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="100"></canvas>


{% endblock content %}
```

When I copied the fiddle example it showed correctly in my dahsboard.html as follows :
[image]

But When I tried to change the datasets in the code as presented in my dashboard.html nothing shows up, labels are updated okay but this is what makes my chart not work :

```
    datasets: [{% for item in qs %}
    {
      label: '{{item.site}}',
      yAxisID: '{{item.site}}',
      data: {{item.turn_over}}' , {% endfor %}
  ]
```

I am sure this is not how it is supposed to be done, I'm a beginner at chart.js , what I want to do is load how many sites I have in my Dummydata table and show their turn over

Thank you

Comment: [edit] your question and add the dummy data you're using, also, check if there are any errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done It was a comma positioning mistake, I checked the console and the problem was that when my if condition was not being checked instead of skipping, it was adding an empty value, meaning that I was getting for example 1, , , , 2 , , , 3 instead of 1,2,3 and the chart was rendering the empty cells, anyway here is the how I was able to fix it for data :

```
data: {
labels: [{% for year in years %} '{{year}}', {% endfor %}],
datasets: [
    {% for site in sites %}

    {
  label: '{{site.site}}',
  yAxisID: 'y',
  borderColor: '{{site.color}}',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',

  data: [ {% for item in qs %}
        {% if item.site == site.site %}


        {{item.turn_over}} ,{% endif %}  {% endfor %}
    ]
}, {% endfor %}

 ]
```

}

[image]